# In page anchors with spaces in the title

Tags: html, anchor

I have a page with some `<h1 name="Header Name">` tags. Notice that the name attribute has a space in it. I want to use an anchor so that I can jump to the heading. I thought that if I added `%20` to replace the spaces it would work, but no.

I am currently swamped, so would prefer not to edit the source and redeploy with each header having an ID or title with hyphens instead of spaces.

```
<!-- non-working example of what I want -->
<a href="mypage.html#Header%20Name" />  
<h1 title="Header Name">Foo</h1>
```

I read through the spec here, but couldn't find an answer. I also could not find an answer via Google or SO.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how anchor tags work.  You can jump to a name of an anchor tag, or an id of any element.  You can never jump to a title attribute, unfortunately.  You would need to modify the html, which you don't want to do, or include javascript to accomplish what you are asking.

Edit: Standards have always said id attributes cannot include spaces, including HTML5, which says this:

> HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the id attribute. The
>   only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are
>   that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty),
>   and that it can’t contain any space characters.

Comment: Oh man I conflated `title` and `name` in my head. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Oh, well in modern browsers, you can use id of any element, or name of an anchor element.  So regardless of space or no, you cannot link to an h1 by name.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the W3C spec https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/types.html#h-6.2

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

No spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The destination anchor should be defined by an `id` attribute, and it must not contain a space. (HTML5 removes all other constraints but disallows a space and an empty value. Older HTML versions are much more restrictive.) So:

```
<h1 id="HeaderName">Foo</h1>
```

Alternatively, you could use an `a` element with `name` attribute, but this is clumsy and outdated (and forbidden in HTML5, though it still works, properly used):

```
<h1><a name="HeaderName">Foo</a></h1>
```

You can use the `name` attribute on a few elements only, not e.g. in `h1`, and only in `a` elements does it have the meaning of acting as a destination anchor.

The `title` attribute can be used on any element (at least as per HTML5), but it is merely an advisory title and has nothing to do with linking.

The construct `<a href="mypage.html#Header%20Name" />` denotes an empty `a` element, a usability nightmare, and does not actually work (it is taken just as a start tag of an element), except in XHTML when served with an XML document type, which you are most probably not doing. So just don’t use the “self-closing” syntax except for elements with empty declared content, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors point to `name` or `id` attributes. It won't find your `title` attribute.

Use `<h1 id="Header Name">` and it should work, but ideally you shouldn't have spaces there.

Comment: No, it should not work: no HTML specification allows a space in the `id` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

There /is/ a way to have an anchor with a space in its name without violating the HTML specification. Use `<a name="my%20name%20with%20spaces"></a>`. The specification makes it clear that you can use percent-encoding when using `<a>` with the `name` attribute. However, when using `id`, you should *not* percent-encode the attribute, and since spaces are disallowed in the `id` attribute, the only option is to use `<a name=...>` instead.

More information: https://blog.markasoftware.com/post/spaces-in-anchor-names/